# How to check if row contains "0" or is empty in DataGridView before doing calculations, and delete this row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

guys!
I need some help with my code.

So, the story is, I had a task to do a form application, where user could count entropy of discrete random variables. He types events and probabilities, and program calculates the entropy.

So I used DataGridView, a button and a TextBox. I've made everything, including restriction, such as "sum of all probabilities must be equal to 1".

But the thing I can't do is - the program itself must delete or ignore rows, which contain "0" or rows, which are empty (because formula of entropy contains log of a number, and log of 0 is an infinity, that's why program will output "NaN - not a number").
The main code is located in "button".

Here is a snippet of it:

```html
for (int z = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; z >= 0; z--)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1[1, z].Value == null)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[z]);
                        }
                        else if (dataGridView1[1, z].Value == "0")
                        { dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[z]);}
                    }
```

The only thing I get after this code, is an error saying, that it can't delete a new "transmitted" (don't know how to translate that to English) line.

This is the whole code, located in "button":

```html
int counter = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1[0, i].Value = counter++;
            }
            double X = 0;
            double A = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                X += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);
            }

            if (X < A && X > A)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cумма вероятностей меньше или больше 1, введите другие значения вероятностей", "АШИППКА", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                double H = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int z = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; z >= 0; z--)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1[1, z].Value == null)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[z]);
                        }
                        else if (dataGridView1[1, z].Value == "0")
                        { dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[z]);}
                    }
                    double p = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);
                    H += p * Math.Log(p, 2.0);
                }
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(-H);
            }
```

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language, that's why there are a lot of mistakes. Please, ask, if you don't understand something.

Help me, please.

Comment: If the `DataGridView.DataSource` is assigned to a `DataTable` or a `BindingSource` then the item has to be removed from the source and cannot be removed directly as you are trying to do. `DataGridViewRows` are not persistent and should not be accessed directly.

Comment: @Loathing oh, that's the problem. So what do I do? How can I solve it? I'm sorry if I'm too dumb, but I'm just a newbie in C#, and I would like a little more detailed answer, because I have some troubles with understanding what you wrote, sorry :c

Comment: @Loathing this can be valuable to post as answer :)

Comment: For this question and future questions, if you are getting an exception, then post the stacktrace and also indicate in your code which line the exception happens on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on comment above.

If your `DataGridView` uses a `DataTable` or a `BindingSource`, e.g.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(...);

DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = table;
```

Anywhere your loops reference `dataGridView1`, replace that with `table` instead.

E.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
  //...
}
```